# Use window.location.href to go 2 pages back and reload

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to tell `window.location.href` to go back 2 pages in history and reload the page that is called?

i only managed to get it to work like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/";
</script>
```

Everything else i try with the command `history.back(-2)` does not work in my case.

Comment: why doesn't it work in your case?

Comment: Well i don´t want a button, i want the page to automatically go back 2 pages. When i give the window.location.href the parameter history.back(-2), nothing happens

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use `history.back(2);`, not `history.back(-2);`.

Comment: `history.back(2)` does not work. `history.go(-2)` is the correct answer. check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History

Answer (score 27):

Try this, it will take you two step back

```
 history.go(-2);
```

eg,

```
<a href="www.mypage.com" onclick="javascript:history.go(-2)"> Link </a>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it works while the other one doesnt...

Answer (score 3):

you can use function history.go(-2) to move backward two pages previously
and history.go(2) to move forward 2 page that you left after you back from 2 pages before

```
<script>
function goBack() {
  window.history.go(-2);
}
</script>
```